# How to Required Field in Suitescript for UI and CSV upload

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Here's the scenario:
If Transaction type is under Order to Cash process (example: sales order or customer invoice, etc.) and Account Type is Revenue or COGS, it will require Product code and region code when adding item line in the sublist.

The Account type will base from the setup of the item.

The rule should apply for both UI in CSV upload across Order to Cash process

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question! It's unclear what is the ask here

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you will need a user event script that runs on the sales order, invoice, and any other record you need validation on. On the script deployment record, select CSV Import and User Interface in the Context Filtering tab.

For better user experience, create a client script that calls the same validation when the user saves the record.